# dialog, trap and SIGTRAP

Tags: bash, trap, dialog, sigtrap

I've seen a lot of examples using dialog tools into scripts with lines as follows:

```
trap "rm $datafile" 0 1 2 5 15
```

What I don't understand is the meaning of SIGNAL 5, ok I know is SIGTRAP. But shame on me, still I don't understand its real significance...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It's not significant now - seems to have been reused from very old scripts which worked around some buggy shell implementation on Solaris.  A better choice would be signal 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a manpage `signal(7)`:

```
Signal         Value   Action   Comment
SIGTRAP        5        Core    Trace/breakpoint trap
```

This signal (as the manpage suggests) is primarily used by debugging tools like `gdb` or `strace`, respectively the `ptrace(2)` system call.  If one process is tracing another process's activity through `ptrace(2)`, `SIGTRAP` will be heavily used to »interrupt« the child, even though the child in most cases won't effectively know this happened (a process monitored through `ptrace(2)` does not necessarily notice which signal had been sent to it, because of the tracer being able to intercept and filter delivered signals and `SIGTRAP` primarily serves to inform the tracer that something noticable happened).

Looking at the `ptrace(2)` manpage is very enlightening in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand its real significance

Let's see how it's caused and used.

The major cause of SIGTRAP is the `int3` instruction.

We can check that with:

```
int main() {
    asm("int3");
    return 0;
}
```

which when run outputs:

```
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

and has exit status `133` = 128 + 5, thus signal 5, SIGTRAP.

GDB inserts `int3` instruction in the text segment, sets up `ptrace`, and lets the program run. When it hits `int3`, `ptrace` wakes up the parent which can the monitor the child's state.

Note that there are also hardware breakpoints, which have a different mechanism: [What is the difference between hardware and software breakpoints? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878716/what-is-the-difference-between-hardware-and-software-breakpoints)

**More about int3**

`int3` has two encodings:

- the regular `int` prefix + `3` which takes up 2 bytes, `int 3` in NASM
- a special 1 byte long encoding, `int3` in NASM

The one byte long encoding is fundamental for GDB. If the instruction were larger than 1 byte, it could overwrite multiple instructions, which would be messy.